# package json script running multiple environment variables

Tags: javascript, scripting, webpack, package.json

In my `package.json` I'm running a script like so:

```
"build-dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"dev\"' --progress --colors -p --define process.env.REACT_APP_GAMESHOW_URL='\"http://api.gameshow.com/contestants\"' --progress --colors"
```

**And it works.**

Basically I'm just trying to run webpack and define a few environment variables:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot

process.env.NODE_ENV=dev

process.env.REACT_APP_GAMESHOW_URL=http://api.gameshow.com/contestants
```

However, I use these parameters multiple times: `-p --define --progress --colors`

Is there a way I can condense the code so it is not repetitive?

Something like:

```
-p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"dev\"' && process.env.REACT_APP_GAMESHOW_URL='\"http://api.gameshow.com/contestants\"' --progress --colors"
```

I tried a bunch of things but they aren't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating a flag like `--progress` and `--colors` doesn't do anything, it's the same as if you had only used it once. The `--define` option can be used multiple times to define multiple values and is totally independent of any other flag/option you use.

Instead of using command line options, you can define these options inside your webpack config. The equivalent `DefinePlugin` is:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('dev'),
      REACT_APP_GAMESHOW_URL: JSON.stringify('http://api.gameshow.com/contestants'),
    }
  })
]
```

Since it's just JavaScript, this also allows you to use `JSON.stringify()` which gets rid of the tedious escaping and using quotes inside quotes. There are several possibilities to change these values based on your environment.

- Separate configs which you specify with `--config path/to/config.js`
- [Exporting a function to use `--env`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env)
- Environment variables e.g. `NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server [options]`

For example you might only have one URL for development and one for production, so you could do something along these lines:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const env = isProd ? 'production' : 'dev';
const url = isProd ? 'http://api.gameshow.com/contestants' : 'http://localhost:3000/contestants';

module.exports = {
  // Rest of your config

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(env),
        REACT_APP_GAMESHOW_URL: JSON.stringify(url),
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Notice how it always checks whether `NODE_ENV` is `production`, so if you don't define `NODE_ENV` at all, you default to the development values, removing another command line option during development. With this config you could run the following for development:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot --progress --colors
```

And for production you only need to add `NODE_ENV=production` and `-p`:

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server -p --content-base src --inline --hot --progress --colors
```

Don't use `-p` in development, that's the production flag and is definitely not helpful to use in development. See [Building for Production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/)
 for more information.

If you prefer, you can also configure other options that you currently specify on the command line, for example [`stats.colors`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) or [`devServer.contentBase`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase).